# Finding expectation from joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Consider the following joint PDF for random variables $X$ and $Y$:

[image]

(the height that the shading going up to on the $y$-axis is $0.5$, it just didn't show up for some reason).

I'm trying to find $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ from this joint PDF, but I'm having a little trouble doing so since the shaded ares are not rectangles so it can't be easily calculated. Help me!

Comment: if this is a joint pdf, it should be $f(x,y)$, but on the plot you clearly have $y=f(x)$

Comment: Given the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f(x,y$, then the expectations can be calculated by summing over the "auxiliary" variable:
$$
E[X] 
= \int x \cdot f(x) \, \mathrm{d} y 
= \int x \cdot \left( \int f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d} y 
 \right) \, \mathrm{d} x .
$$ I am afraid your joint pdf is not clear to me however, so I can't be more specific, but hopefully that can get you started? I am unsure as how to interpret your graph.

Comment: The graph is as follows -- $A$ is the probability density per area. For normalization with the graph, we must have $A=4$.

Answer (score 1):

We interpret the picture as follows: the joint distribution is *uniform* on the shaded region. Then the joint density is $4$ on the shaded region, and $0$ elsewhere.

For the expectation of $X$, there is no reason to compute. Symmetry shows that $E(X)=0.5$.

For the expectation of $Y$, we could also use geometry, but let us integrate. So we want to find 
$$\iint_S 4y\,dx\,dy,$$
where $S$ is the shaded region.
We can split the integral into two parts, the left part and the right part.
For the left part, $x$ goes from $0$ to $y$, and then $y$ goes from $0$ to $0.5$. We get fairly quickly that the double integral is $\frac{1}{6}$.

We can set up and evaluate a similar but more complicated integral for the right part. But this is unnecessary, since the geometry shows that the integral over the right part is also $\frac{1}{6}$, for a total of $\frac{1}{3}$.

Alternately, we could find the (marginal) distribution of $Y$, and then use that to find $E(Y)$. I prefer the double integral approach.

Comment: Ok -- this makes sense now that I think about it. Just out of curiosity, how would you go about finding the marginal distribution of $Y$? It would be defined as

$$
\int_S f(x,y) \, dx,
$$

but I don't see an easy way to go about computing this.

Comment: $x\in(0,y)\cup(1-y,1)$ so $f_Y(y) = \int_{0}^{y} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \operatorname d x+\int_{1-y}^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x = 4(y-0)+4(1-(1-y))=8y$

Comment: We could find the cdf, and then differentiate. But it is easier to "integrate out" $x$. For any $y$, $x$ goes from $0$ to $y$, and then skips some stuff. It then hits the line $x+y=1$, so $x$ now goes from $1-y$ to $1$. We are integrating the constant function $y$. There are two intervals of length $y$, so the marginal density is $8y$, where $y$ goes from $0$ to $0.5$.

Comment: The "integration" stuff is kind of silly, it really is all pure geometry.

Comment: @AndréNicolas what will the limits for joint pdf?